# Where can I get the Play source code from?

Tags: playframework

Where is the Play source code stored? I don't really "get" what I downloaded - some sort of activator thing? I mean, I can *run* play, but I want the source code.

The Play site talks about downloading a Git downloader to get the source. I don't have anything to do with Git source repositories (not for any reason, I just can't be bothered with it); is there just "a link" for the source?

Comment: like github? https://github.com/playframework/playframework/

Comment: if you are wondering where its stored locally, then internally ivy is used, so in your home folder, there should be .ivy2 folder. all dependencies are cached there. you can search for it there. If you want to look for src on github, then https://github.com/playframework/playframework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the link on the front page of the [Play website](https://playframework.com/).

[image: Play sources]

Comment: thanks! i thought that was a weird github-liking button